# How write data at to pointer in structure

Tags: c, pointers

I have this structure, and I would like to pass the data to Example_Data->data.

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t *data; /*!< Pointer to allocated data. */
  uint32_t size; /*!< Length of data allocated. */
} Example_Data
```

Since this is an array data type, unfortunately I have no idea how I should pass the data to this pointer.

I have a question, how to append new data to this pointer?

Comment: `Example_Data my_data; my_data->data = malloc(SOME_SIZE);`

Comment: Or are you saying the pointer is already allocated and you want to store data in it? If so that would be `my_data->data[i] = some_uint8_value;` or use `memcpy` to copy more than one byte. It is not clear exactly what your problem is so some clarification wold help.

Comment: There is no array here.  The data type is a struct that contains a pointer and a size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate memory to `data`, then copy your data with `memcpy`:

```
uint8_t someData[100] = {0};
Example_Data exampleData = {0};
exampleData.data = malloc(sizeof(someData));
if(exampleData.data != NULL){
    memcpy(exampleData.data, someData, sizeof(someData);
}else{
    //malloc failed, handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
        uint8_t *data;
        uint32_t size;
} Example_Data;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        Example_Data e;
        e.size = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 32;
        e.data = malloc(e.size * sizeof *e.data);
        if( e.data == NULL ){
                perror("malloc");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        for( unsigned i = 0; i < e.size; i++ ){
                e.data[i] = i;
                printf("%d%c", i, i % 8 == 7 ? '\n' : '\t');
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```